# windows phone 8.1 RT Zxing.net implementation : issue with CapturePhotoToStreamAsync

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, zxing

I'm using ZXing.net to create a UserControl for scanning barcode into a Windows Phone 8.1 RT app using the camera.

The barcode are decoded well but i'm having freezes on the UI when the method CapturePhotoToStreamAsync is called, even it is awaited.
It takes about 600 ms to execute.

I'm testing the app into the emulator.

The code below is executed in an async method :

```
// Preview of the camera    
await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
VideoCapture.Source = _mediaCapture;
VideoCapture.FlowDirection = Windows.UI.Xaml.FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();

VideoEncodingProperties res = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;
ImageEncodingProperties iep = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateBmp();

iep.Height = res.Height;
iep.Width = res.Width;

var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
{
     TryHarder = true,
     AutoRotate = true
};

WriteableBitmap wB = new WriteableBitmap((int)res.Width, (int)res.Height);
while (_result == null)
{
     using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
     {
        await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(iep, stream);

        stream.Seek(0);
        await wB.SetSourceAsync(stream);

        _result = barcodeReader.Decode(wB);
      }
 }

 await _mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
 //callback to handle result
 ScanCallback(_result.Text);
```

What can I do to prevent the UI from freezing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily you don't have to capture photo to decode QRCode/Barcode on Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime. It is a quite new solution actually, but it works: https://github.com/mmaitre314/VideoEffect#realtime-video-analysis-and-qr-code-detection 
After istalling the nuget package, you can easily decode barcodes realtime, without the need of calling CapturePhotoToStreamAsync. The only drawback is that you can only target ARM. You can find the sample code on the site. Or you can contact me, and I can send you the part of my project where I use this.

Comment: It seems a good solution. I added a button to take a picture then anaylizing rather than scanning in real-time. But I'll try your solution. However, does the SDK works only for MS/Nokia phones or other brands (Acer, Alcatel One Touche, etc...) ?

Comment: It only support MS/Nokia phones for now. But at the moment I don't think it's a problem. As of 2013, Nokia accounted for 90 percent of the Windows Phone market(http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2309660/nokia-accounts-for-90-percent-of-the-windows-phone-market). And I don't think it has changed a lot since then. So you will still support most of the devices.

Comment: Not true. The Lumia Imaging SDK works fine on any Windows Phone (8.0, 8.1), and any Windows RT tablet or Windows PC (8.1 universal app target). It's only a matter of branding.

Comment: So in other words, ARM/x86/x64 are all supported. If you create a universal app (which you should), you can easily cover the Windows market as well.

Comment: Ok, than it's not the Lumia Imaging SDKwhich restricts my Windows Phone project to ARM, but since I installed the Video Effect SDK (which depends on the Lumia Imaging SDK), I can only target ARM.

Comment: is it possible to make this vertical?

Comment: capture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);capture.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees); and in the xaml set the CaptureElement's Stretch="UniformToFill"

Answer (score 0):

i always get better results when i use the camera to take a picture first (lets you focus on the correct place where the barcode is) and then send the picture for barcode recognition.

the stuttering is caused because you try to keep checking the live feed for barcodes which can be hard on the CPU (especially for ARM devices)

```
var dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
StorageFile file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
// initialize with 1,1 to get the current size of the image
var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);
// and create it again because otherwise the WB isn't fully initialized and decoding
// results in a IndexOutOfRange
writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
stream.Seek(0);
writeableBmp.SetSource(stream);

var result = ScanBitmap(writeableBmp);
string barcode = "";
if (result != null)
{
    barcode = result.Text;
}
```

and here the ScanBitmap method:

```
    private Result ScanBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp)
    {
        var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
        {
            Options = new ZXing.Common.DecodingOptions()
            {
                TryHarder = true
            },
            AutoRotate = true
        };
        var result = barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBmp);

        if (result != null)
        {
            CaptureImage.Source = writeableBmp;
        }

        return result;
    }
```